# Как по клику можно сделать раскрывающийся блок (React Redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
class CompanyPage extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            info: {
                display: 'none !important'
            }
        };
    }

onBtnClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var block = document.querySelector('.selected-company-info__text');

        block.setState({
            info: { display: 'block !important' }
        });

    }

render () {
        const {
            props: {   },
            state: { info }
            } = this;

const style = {
            info: {
                block: info.block
            }
        };

return(
<a
                        href="javascript://"
                        className="button button--white button--center"
                        onClick={this.onBtnClickHandler}>
                        УЗНАТЬ БОЛЬШЕ О ...
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div style={style.block} className="selected-company-info__text visible-tablet disable-mobile">
                    some text
                </div>
);

}

}

export default CompanyPage;
```

Привожу пример компонента, redux только начинаю изучать, поэтому могут ошибки разного рода. Прошу на них указать или дать пример другой реализации данного момента.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Используем компонент с внутренним состоянием:

```
var Foldable = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){ return {open: true} },

  toggleOpen: function(){ this.setState({open: !this.state.open}) },

  render: function(){
    var className = this.state.open ? "opened" : "closed";

    return (
      <div class="foldable">
        <div class="header" onClick={ this.toggleOpen }>
          { this.props.header }
        </div>
        <div className={ className }>
          { this.props.children }
        </div>         
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

И соответствующий стиль:

```
.foldable .opened, .foldable .closed   
  transition: 1s;
.foldable .opened
  max-height: 100em;
.foldable .closed
  max-height: 0em;
```

Применение компонента:

```
<Foldable header="Заголовок">Lorem ipsum на много строк...</Foldable>
<Foldable header="Заголовок2">итд</Foldable>
<Foldable header="Заголовок3">итп</Foldable>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, один момент только хочу уточнить: а если высота неизвестна?

Comment: просто увеличьте `max-height` для `.opened` до `1000px` или более - на реальной высоте это не отразиться, т.к. `height` не задан

Comment: @Jarvis Если ответ вам помог, укажите его как правильный.